# Python. Ошибка при правильно указанном пути к файлу

Tags: python

```
f = open("D:\Python\port.txt")
```

Путь полностью правильный, у меня виндовс, но почему то срабатывает эта ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Amir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/h.py", line 2, in <module>
    f = open("D:\Python\port.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Python\\port.txt'
```

Comment: @Эникейщик это не объясняет, откуда магическим образом нарисовались запятые с пробелами (и в Python отсутствует `\p`)

Comment: Простите я указал старую ошибку, сейчас поправлю...

Comment: Тогда поехали дальше — а почему вы решили, что путь правильный? Вы проверяли, что у вас везде в именах именно английские буквы, а не похожие на них русские буквы, например?

Comment: Да, я могу скинуть скрин

Comment: Я пытался даже через pathlib но и с ним та же ошибка

Comment: @TerrrassaFlazer на скрине невозможно определить, английские там буквы или русские, они же выглядят одинаково

Comment: Сейчас я добавил в путь туда еще и This PC  и у меня высветилась другая ошибкаTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Amir/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/h.py", line 2, in <module>
    f = open("This PC\D:\Python\port.txt", "r")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'This PC\\D:\\Python\\port.txt'

Comment: @TerrrassaFlazer ну это вы уже какой-то совсем полный бред пытаетесь делать. Лучше наличие русских букв в именах проверьте

Comment: .........Хорошо.

Comment: Ах да, и ещё проверьте, отображаются ли в вашем файловом менеджере расширения файлов, а то вдруг у вас там на самом деле `port.txt.txt` и файловый менеджер предательски скрывает этот факт от вас

Comment: Нет, все верно, нет русских букв и расширение тоже такое же как я указал.

Comment: Ладно, тогда скиньте скрин, потому что я не знаю что ещё предположить

Comment: Если взять, скопировать текст `D:\Python\port.txt` и вставить в проводнике - файл откроется?

Comment: @SwaD Да откроется

Comment: Ну а если указать так `open("D:/Python/port.txt")`

Comment: @andreymal я не могу отправить скрин

Comment: @SwaD нет выходит та же ошибка

Comment: Большое вам спасибо что пытались помочь, я смог решить проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
f = open('D:\\Python\\port.txt')
```

или

```
f = open(r'D:\Python\port.txt')
```

или

```
os.chdir(r'D:\Python')
f = open('port.txt')
```

Comment: Не работает все равно((

Comment: А если создать папку C:\Users\Amir\Python\ скинуть в нее файл port.txt и попробовать оттуда открыть?

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую...

Comment: Все вышло, спасибо большое.